# Inherit from a built-in class

Tags: python, inheritance

I would like to add some methods to the datetime.datetime object. It seems that we can only do that by inheriting from it and adding this new method. The problem is that this method need to update the day/month/year values of the base class and that i can't call the base init method with the new parameters.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your example "addMonth" makes no sense. What method is it you want to add, specifically?

Comment: Could you show the code for a specific example of a method you tried to add that didn't work (like "addMonth" or whatever)?

Answer (score 2):

You can call the base class `__init__` method.

```
class Foo(datetime.datetime):
    def __init__(self, argument):
         datetime.datetime.__init__(self, argument)
```

The key point here is that you need to call the `__init__` method explicitly and you need to manually supply the first `self` argument that Python normally supplies for you.

Also, don't forget about the `*` and `**` calling techniques to catch arguments that you don't want to deal with manually but that you still want to be able to pass to the parent constructor.

Comment: `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` (or `super(Foo, self)...` in Python 2) is made of win. Every `__init__` override should start with this.

Comment: does this allow me to add a method addMonth for inst to the class Foo and correctly updates all the internal members of datetime ?

Comment: @Dave, you can certainly add methods and any reference to an attribute of `self` will be valid and reflected in all of the other attributes. I'm not sure that I totally understand your question though.

Comment: if you try to add a method that a month for ex ( just do self.month += 1 and inititalize the constructor with 2010/01/01) . you will get this exception AttributeError: attribute 'month' of 'datetime.date' objects is not writable

Comment: Subclassing doesn't magically alter instances of the base class. You need to create objects of YourSpecialDate not the base datetime.

Comment: @Dave, it's because datetime is immutable apparently. You need to override the `__new__` method instead. After the object is constructed, you can't change it. If you want a mutable datetime class, you might want to consider a wrapper class that internally maintains a datetime instance and creates a new instance to reflect any changes.

Comment: yes that is what i wanted to avoid , because i still want to expose the same interface than datetime to all the other python libraries. Of course i can create this wrapper that will redefine all the methods , not optimal ; But i agree with you aaron your method work and may be the only way.

Comment: @Dave: You can create a wrapper class that automatically dispatches most of the method calls to the wrapped datetime instance by giving it a custom `__getattr__ ()` method. See my answer to the question [Intercepting module calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392855/intercepting-module-calls-python/4394460#4394460) and note how the `class _renderer` is written for an example of how easily this can be done. If you add some code with your question, I'll post something more specific.