# Wrap matplotlib to pipe calls back to main process

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

**Motivation** I have an existing code base that consists of a library of functions for reading off disk, doing some computation (largely using numpy and scipy) and then plotting results.  Additionally, I have a function for doing "meta-plotting", meaning it takes in a list of files, and a list of requested plot types, which it loops through to generate a grid of plots in a pdf.

Given that the computation done for each file is completely independent, I was hoping it would be fairly easy to use the `multiprocessing` module to get an instant speed up.  However, (unsurprisingly) life doesn't seem to be that simple.

**Dummy example**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from numpy.random import random
from time import sleep

def computeAndPlot(a):
    sleep(2) # pretend we're working hard
    plt.imshow(random((10,10))) # plot the "result"

if __name__== "__main__":
    Pool().map_async(computeAndPlot,[(ii,) for ii in xrange(40)]).get()
```

**Question** How can I use `matplotlib` with `multiprocessing`?  I'm looking for a solution which is completely transparent at the point calls are made to `matplotlib` (e.g `plt.plot()` and `plt.hold()`), but it can be complicated-ish at the point the process is launched.  Really I'd like to be able to plot from multiple processes into different axes in the same figure.  Note that I don't actually care about parallelising the plotting itself, it's the file reading and computation which I want to do in parallel.

**Possible solution A** I had some success using `plt.pause(0.0001)` followed by `plt.close()`, which is pretty pointless, but did demonstrate that you can indeed generate figures simultaneously from multiple processes, and presumably save each of them separately. Perhaps this is the most sensible solution, but annoyingly I don't see how you could use it to generate a grid of plots in a pdf..unless you do some fancy pdf merging at the end.

**Possible solution B** I wondered whether it was possible to wrap matplotlib so as to pipe all function calls back to the main process.  I imagine this would work by having a `pipedMPL` function wrapper which would be applied to the first argument to `map_async`.  The main process would receive plotting commands and issue them to the relevant axes (it ought to know the source process so it can choose the correct axes).  I feel like this could be quite a nice solution, but I expect it to be rather complicated to write the required wrapper to deal with instance methods and everything (?) correctly.  *Question:* is this worth pursuing in terms of likely difficulty and usefulness to other people or is there already a better solution already, also are there examples of similar module-wrapping things out there (note that this is not basic monkey-patching of one or two methods, I want to write a generic wrapper for everything).

**Possible solution C** I looked briefly at the possibility of pickling an axes produced on a subprocess and sending it back to the main process for use in the main figure.  Perhaps this is possible, but I couldn't make it work..I just got pickling errors.

Any other ideas?

---

**Update**

After several hours of work, I have got a basic version of solution B working: [monobrow.py (gist)](https://gist.github.com/d1manson/9943712).

In terms of wrapping a module easily, it's actually really simple (as state [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4393011/2399799)):

```
import sys
sys.module['matplotlib'] = MyFakeMatplotlib()
```